# VBA to Find all rows with numeric values and return column header

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to convert one spreadsheet that contains dates across row2 and names down column B. Each person's worked hours are listed across the rows under the date worked. 
I want to convert this into lines of data in a new tab with columns: name, date, hours worked.

So far I've used VBA to pull all the names and duplicate them down column B for the number of days with hours worked (i.e. if they've worked 3 days, their name is listed 3 times). But I still need to figure out how to return the date and hours worked to the second page. The first image is the original page. Second is the desired layout.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this problem is to do the following:

1. Load the relevant range from the source sheet into an array of dimensions h x w. Let's call the array source(h, w).
2. This array should have the following attributes:

   1. The top-left cell (or source(0,0)) should not have any relevant values.
   2. The values in the left-hand column, or everything in source(x, 0), should be the names of the employees, starting with the second row (which would be source(1,0) if you are using Option Base 0, which is the default).
   3. The values in the top row, or everything in source(0, y), should be the weeks. Again, you need to start with the second column (which would be in source(0, 1)) because the first column is empty.
   4. The values within the rest of the array is the number of days and hours they've worked.
3. Create a new array that is the length h*w in length in the first dimension and 3 in length in the second dimension, and use this array to store the results of the next step.
4. Now that you have this array populated, you can loop through it with two nested For loops, starting with the value at source(1,1). When you are looping through this array, you will need to capture the following values:

   1. source(x,0) - this is the employee name
   2. source(0,y) - this is the employee week
   3. source(x,y) - this is the number of days and hours the employee worked

Let me know if this is helpful.